# Return object of Type T from XML data

Tags: c#, xml, object

I am parsing an XML and able to extract data into List of object using below code. But the front end uses an type of T binding data object which is currently working. Once I return ienumerable it is not working. How can I convert this enumerable to type of T?

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Feed));
        var xmlfeed = new XMLfeed();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(doc.OuterXml))
        {
            xmlfeed = (XMLfeed)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }
        foreach (var properties in XMLfeed?.values)
        {
            var feedObj= new FeedObj();
            feedObj.Name = properties?.Name;
            feedObj.Value = properties?.Value;                
            lstObjfeed.Add(feed);
        }

        return lstObjfeed.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast) from LINQ?

So something like `lstObjfeed.AsEnumerable().Cast<T>()`.